# Matplotlib issue with grid layout and shapes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to create something like the picture? cause I just can't get it to work. Mine isn't showing shapes on the grid for some reason. Any help would be appreciated

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
# Data for plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(8,7))

#use add_patch instead, it's more clear what you are doing
ax.plot([1,5,2],[2,3,4],color="cyan")
rect = Rectangle((5,5),6,6, fill= False)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect)

ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.ylim(1400,2300)
plt.xlim(34,48)
plt.xlabel("inches")
plt.ylabel("weight (lbs)")
plt.title('Váha a vyváženie lietadla Cessna 172N')
plt.legend(["Utility","Normal category"])
plt.grid()
plt.plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.ylim(1400,2300), plt.xlim(34,48)` scales your graph so that your patch is outside the viewing field.

Comment: All your plot elements are in the region `1<x<11` and `2<y<11`, but you set the xlim and ylim to much larger ranges, excluding that region. Comment out your `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` lines and you will see your plot elements

Comment: BTW, `plt.gca().add_patch(rect)` and `ax.add_patch(rect)` do in your code exactly the same thing. Omit the former; the latter is sufficient.

Comment: thanks! at least its finally showing the shapes but is it possible to create something like the photo with this method?

Comment: you could use a `Polygon` instead of a `Rectangle` patch: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html#matplotlib-patches-polygon

Comment: and what should the ranges of the polygons be? cause it still only shows when i put my ranges in a hashtag lol (im not exactly great at this)